# CustomResponseInterface class does not exist in API

Tags: magento2.4, rest-api

i got error when i call API everytime.

> [2022-08-29 10:26:45] report.CRITICAL: Report ID:
> webapi-630c9465cd611; Message: Class
> \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface[] does not exist
> {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: -1): Report ID:
> webapi-630c9465cd611; Message: Class
> \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface[] does not
> exist at
> /var/www/html/wanderlust2/m2_new_staging/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208,
> ReflectionException(code: -1): Class
> \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface[] does not
> exist at
> /var/www/html/XYZ/m2_new_staging/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php:166)"} []

below is my code..

**/app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/CustomInterface.php**

```
<?php

namespace Rental\Totalrevenue\Api;

interface CustomInterface
{
/**
* GET for Post api
* @param string $value
* @return string
*/

//public function getPost($value);

/**
 * GET for Post api
 * @param string $param
 * @return string
 * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
 */
public function getTotalRevenue();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function PendingPayment();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function getPendingRequests();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function getTotalBooking();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function getTotalPartners();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function getTotalCustomers();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function getCompletedTrips();

/**
* @api
* @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
*/
public function getCancelledTrips();
}
```

**app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/Api/Data/CustomResponseInterface.php**

```
<?php
namespace Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data;

/**
 * Interface CustomResponseInterfaceFactory
 */
interface CustomResponseInterface
{
    const CODE = 'code';
    const MESSAGE = 'message';
    const DATA = 'data';
    const SUCCESS = 'success';


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCode();

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMessage();

    /**
     * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface[]
     */
    public function getData();

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getSuccess();

}
```

**app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" 
                type="Rental\Totalrevenue\Model\Api\Custom"/>
    <!-- Response interface -->

    <preference for="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface" 
                type="Rental\Totalrevenue\Model\Response\CustomResponse"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/etc/webapi.xml**

```
<route url="/V1/payment/pendingpayment" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="PendingPayment"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

<route url="/V1/request/pendingrequest/post/" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getPendingRequests"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

<route url="/V1/booking/totalbooking/post/" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getTotalBooking"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

<route url="/V1/partners/totalpartners/post/" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getTotalPartners"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>    

<route url="/V1/customers/totalcustomers/post/" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getTotalCustomers"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route> 

<route url="/V1/trips/completedtrips/post/" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getCompletedTrips"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route> 

<route url="/V1/trips/cancelledtrips/post/" method="GET">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getCancelledTrips"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>

<!-- <route url="/V1/custom/custom-api/:value" method="POST">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getPost"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
     </resources>
</route> -->

<!-- <route method="GET" url="/V1/custom/post">
    <service class="Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface" method="getPost2"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route> -->
```

**app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/Model/Api/Custom.php**

```
  <?php
    
    namespace Rental\Totalrevenue\Model\Api;
    
    use Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\CustomInterface;
    use Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface;
    use Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterfaceFactory;
    use Exception;
    use Wanderlust\Booking\Model\RiderdetailFactory;
    use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
    use Magento\Backend\Model\Dashboard\Period;
    use Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection;
    use Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory;
    use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
    use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
    use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
    use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Group\Collection as CustomerGroup;
    
    class Custom implements CustomInterface
    {
      protected $_collectionFactory;
      protected $logger;
      //protected $request;
      protected $customerGroup;  
    
      /** @var RequestInterface */
        protected $request;
    
    
      public function __construct(
        \Wanderlust\Customer\Model\AdminuserFactory $adminuserFactory,
        \Wanderlust\Operator\Model\TransactionFactory $transactionFactory,    
        RiderdetailFactory $riderDetailFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        RequestInterface $request,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        CustomerGroup $customerGroup,
        CustomResponseInterfaceFactory $customResponseInterfaceFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
      )
      {        
        $this->_riderDetailFactory = $riderDetailFactory;
        $this->transactionFactory = $transactionFactory;
        $this->adminuserFactory = $adminuserFactory;
        $this->customerGroup = $customerGroup; 
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->_customResponseInterfaceFactory = $customResponseInterfaceFactory;
      }
    
    
      private function setResponse($status, $message, $customer)
        {
            return $this->_customResponseInterfaceFactory->create([
                'data' => [
                    CustomResponseInterface::CODE  => $status,
                    CustomResponseInterface::DATA    => $customer,
                    CustomResponseInterface::MESSAGE => $message,
                    CustomResponseInterface::SUCCESS => ($status == 200) ? true : false,
                ]
            ]);
        }
    
      /**
      * @inheritdoc
      */
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getTotalRevenue()
      {   
          /* Get Current Store Name */
          /*$storeName = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getName();    
          echo $storeName;*/
          
          /* Get Current Website ID */
          /*$websiteId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
          echo $websiteId;*/
    
          /* Get Current Store ID */
          /*$storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
          echo $storeId;*/
          
          /*$collection = $this->adminuserFactory->create()->getCollection();
          foreach ($collection as $product) {
               print_r($product->getData('user_type'));
           }return $collection;*/
    
          //Get the date which was 14 days ago.
          //$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-14 day'));
    
          $adminuserGuids = $this->adminuserFactory->create()->getCollection();
          $rental_admin_type = $adminuserGuids->addFieldToFilter('user_type','rental_super_admin');
          //echo $rental_admin_type->getSelect()->__toString();    
          
          if ($rental_admin_type) {
            
              $isFilter = $this->request->getParam('Default Store View') || $this->request->getParam('1') || 
                          $this->request->getParam('default');
    
              $period = $this->request->getParam('period', Period::PERIOD_1_YEAR); // 1y, 2y
              if($period == '1y'){
                //echo "PERIOD_1_YEAR";
                // PERIOD_24_HOURS means Today   
                // PERIOD_1_MONTH  means Last Month
                //$period = $this->request->getParam('1y'); // 1y, 2y
                //$period = '1y';
                  
                /* @var $collection Collection */
    //->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$startDate, 'to'=>$endDate));
    
              /*
                $now = new \DateTime();
                
                $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
                ->addFilter('startDate', ['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
                ->addFilter('endDate', ['gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
                ->calculateTotals(            
                  $isFilter
                );
              */
    
                $collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addCreateAtPeriodFilter(
                  $period
                )->calculateTotals(            
                  $isFilter
                );
                //echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
    
                if ($this->request->getParam('Default Store View')) {
                    $collection->addFieldToFilter('1', $this->request->getParam('Default Store View'));
                } else {
                    if ($this->request->getParam('1')) {
                        $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite($this->request->getParam('1'))->getStoreIds();
                        $collection->addFieldToFilter('1', ['in' => $storeIds]);
                    } else {
                        if ($this->request->getParam('default')) {
                            $storeIds = $this->_storeManager->getGroup($this->request->getParam('default'))->getStoreIds();
                            $collection->addFieldToFilter('1', ['in' => $storeIds]);
                        } elseif (!$collection->isLive()) {
                            $collection->addFieldToFilter(
                                '1',
                                ['eq' => $this->_storeManager->getStore(Store::ADMIN_CODE)->getId()]
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                $collection->load();
                
                $writer = new \Laminas\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/totalrevenue.log');
                $logger = new \Laminas\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);
                $logger->info('Total Revenue Logs');
                //$logger->info($collection->getSelect());
                $logger->info(print_r($collection->getData(), true));
    
                $totals = $collection->getFirstItem();            
                return $totals->getRevenue();
                //return 'Total Revenue $param ' . $param;
              }
          }
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function PendingPayment()
      { 
        /*$collection = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending');
        echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();*/
    
       /*$collection = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending');    
       //echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();
       $panding_payment = count($collection);
       return $panding_payment;*/
    
        try {
            $panding_payments = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending'); 
            echo $panding_payments->getSelect()->__toString();
            //if (!empty($panding_payments)) {
            if (count($panding_payments)) {
                return $this->setResponse(200, "Success", $panding_payments);
            } else {
                return $this->setResponse(404, "No Record Found", []);
            }
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->setResponse(500, $e->getMessage(), null);
        }
    
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getPendingRequests()
      {    
        //$collection = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending')->getData();
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getTotalBooking()
      {    
        //$riderDetailFactory = $this->_riderDetailFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('booking_series_id', $booking_series_id)->addFieldToFilter('cancel_item', 'y');
        $riderDetailFactory = $this->_riderDetailFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $total_booking = count($riderDetailFactory);
        return $total_booking;    
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getTotalPartners()
      {
        //$collection = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending')->getData();
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getTotalCustomers()
      {
        echo "Total Customers";
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getCompletedTrips()
      {
        //$collection = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending')->getData();
      }
    
      /**
      * @api
      * @return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface
      */
      public function getCancelledTrips()
      {
        //$collection = $this->transactionFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('payment_status', 'pending')->getData();
      }
    
      /*public function getPost($value)
      {
        $response = ['success' => false];
    
        try {
          // Your Code here
       
          $response = ['success' => true, 'message' => $value];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
          $response = ['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()];
          $this->logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
        $returnArray = json_encode($response);
        return $returnArray;
      }*/
    
      
    }
```

**app/code/Rental/Totalrevenue/Model/Response/CustomResponse.php**

```
<?php
namespace Rental\Totalrevenue\Model\Response;

use Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject;
use Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface;

/**
 * Class CustomResponseInterface
 */
class CustomResponse extends AbstractSimpleObject implements CustomResponseInterface
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getCode()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::CODE);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getMessage()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::MESSAGE);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::DATA);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSuccess()
    {
        return $this->_get(self::SUCCESS);
    }
}
```

Comment: what i do mistake here? i don't know..

Comment: You have a mess in PHPDoc. Magento uses Reflection for work with API and you need to writes correct PHPDocs for all related methods.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk in which file i have mess PHPDoc? please let me know...

Comment: In your case the issue is related to `CustomResponseInterface::getData` `@return`. Just replace it to `array`. Little bit strange that `getData` returns array of self. Don't forget to fix `CustomInterface` PHPDocs

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk did you mean i need to change return \Rental\Totalrevenue\Api\Data\CustomResponseInterface to array